# adding extra image when the UIButton remain pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I want to add an extra image when my button remains pressed.
Is it possible in iphone?

Comment: set highlighted image to that button

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean when the user makes a long press on the cell (tap down and keep finger down)?
You can add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` element to your button and specify its target and action like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
[longPressRecognizer release];
```

This will call the `-longPress:` method when a user long presses on the button. The callback function could look like this:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        // do something like add an image
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Of course Yes,

First take a custom button and set any image to it.

Then bind the following method wih Touch Down event of the button.

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouchedImage:(id)sender
{
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this but i want to add an extra image when the button is in highlighted state

Comment: Please read the above code again its in the highlighted state when the image "selected.png" is set

Answer (score 0):

Set button highlighted image and make it highlighted = YES  when button pressed. This should work I guess.